# Are there any tweaks for Lion's autocorrect?

Tags: macos, auto-complete, autocorrect

I've found that Lion's autocorrect handles technical terminology abysmally.  Are there any configuration tweaks that adjust its behavior around words that might represent technical terms?

Answer (score 4):

For specific terms you find are getting "corrected" often, you could add them to the text substitution list as substitutes of themselves. That should work as a sort of whitelist to stop them from being autocorrected improperly.

Open up the **Language & Text** panel in System Preferences, and on the *Text* tab, click the + to add a new substitution. Enter the word you want whitelisted into both fields.

[image: Language & Text preferences]

Comment: Interesting approach, but simply clicking 'learn spelling' sounds easier.  In any case, I'm asking about general solutions, not teaching it every stupid acronym.  If anything, that'll make matters worse by decreasing my paranoia.  Apple should have made shift-space disable autocorrect, but a plugin could likely achieve this.

Comment: Yes!!! I've been trying to make the auto correct to correct my name from Ramon to Ramón... I just don't want to do the key sequence to place the accentuation mark over the "o" (command key+"e" then the vowel to be accentuated) every time I type my name.